# Kerberos master-slave setup : Database propagation, and KDC & KADMIN switching

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I am trying to setup Kerberos on Redhat with slaves and database propagation (not incremental). I am going through MIT's documentation for [KDC installation and configuration](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/install.html). Currently, I have three doubts/issues:

1. **Do we need kpropd running on slave KDC, even if we do not have incremental propagation ?**

   I started xinetd service, and tried propagating database (without starting kpropd, as I have not configured incremental propagation), and it gave me an error:

   ```
   kprop: Connection refused while connecting to server
   ```

   However, when I started kpropd in the same setup without any configuration change, I was able to successfully propagate the database.

   As per the [document](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/install_kdc.html#install-the-slave-kdcs), it says

   > [Re]start inetd daemon. Alternatively, start kpropd as a stand-alone
   >   daemon. This is required when incremental propagation is enabled.

   I went through MIT's [Troubleshooting page](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/troubleshoot.html#kprop-con-refused) as well, and it said the same, i.e. inetd can run kprop.

   My inetd.conf:

   ```
   krb5_prop stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/kpropd kpropd
   ```
2. **Do we need to add Kerberos Administration Server (admin_server) for slave KDC in krb5.conf? OR In other words, can we have more than one admin_server properties configured in krb5.conf?**

   Since we are configuring a master-slave setup and can switch to a slave KDC creating it a new master at any point of time. We would need to start a Kerberos Administration Server (kadmind) on the new master, as well. Do we need to have hosts for both the admin servers listed in the krb5.conf file?

   I tried adding both the hosts, but it turns out that this property only picks the last configured one.

   My krb5.conf looks like:

   ```
   [libdefaults]
   default_realm = KRB.MY.DOMAIN
   dns_lookup_realm = false
   dns_lookup_kdc = false
   ticket_lifetime = 1h
   renew_lifetime = 2h
   forwardable = true

   [realms]
   KRB.MY.DOMAIN = {
   kdc = old-master-host.my.domain
   kdc = new-master-host.my.domain
   admin_server = old-master-host.my.domain
   admin_server = new-master-host.my.domain
   }

   [domain_realm]
   .my.domain = KRB.MY.DOMAIN
   ```

   In such a case, admin server would be looked only at `new-master-host.my.domain`, even if it is running on `old-master-host.my.domain`.
3. **Can we start Kerberos Administration Server on a slave KDC machine, as specified in [MIT documentation](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/install_kdc.html#switching-master-and-slave-kdcs)?**

   I tried starting Kerberos Administration Server (kadmind) on my new master and I got an error:

   ```
   Error. This appears to be a slave server, found kpropd.acl
   ```

   Is it not advisable to start the Administration server on the slave machine or do we have to [re]move the kpropd.acl file before we can start Administration server?

I would really appreciate any pointers or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Yes you need to have kpropd and krb5kdc services running on Secondary KDC server.
2. There is no need to setup second admin server in Master-Secondary KDC setup. You may copy krb5.conf and kdc.conf files from Master KDC to Secondary KDC.
3. You cannot start kadmind on Secondary KDC server if you have kpropd service running.

I've used this RH Documentation page to setup Master-Secondary KDC servers: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Smart_Cards/Configuring_a_Kerberos_5_Server.html

Comment: I am doing similar setup but my CentOS does not have inetd daemon setup. Can you please tell me how to setup and start inetd daemon? I am stuck at manually propagating the database to slave KDC

Comment: Manually propagating the database to slave KDC is giving me error:                                        kprop: Client not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials

Comment: @earl apologies that the comment comes in quite late, but yes you can very well run kprop. All you need is to add the two hosts into KDC, and then have their keytabs created and kept in /etc/krb5.keytab